# How to set thumbnail image in video object tag?

Tags: html, object

I am using object tag to play video in browser.

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="fitvid473410"><param name="movie" value="http://demo.assetbank.co.uk/assetbank-standard/tools/jwplayer/player.swf">
<param name="flashvars" value="file=http://win-hk4iec2ge2r:1111/sites/KL007/Lists/KLDocumentLibrary/other.mp4&amp;autostart=false&amp;image=?previewFileLocation?&amp;backcolor=000000&amp;frontcolor=EEEEEE&amp;lightcolor=FFFFFF&amp;screencolor=000000&amp;autostart=false&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;provider=video&amp;duration?">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
<param name="scale" value="default">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<embed id="player1" width="300px" height="500px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://demo.assetbank.co.uk/assetbank-standard/tools/jwplayer/player.swf" flashvars="file=http://win-hk4iec2ge2r:1111/sites/KL007/Lists/KLDocumentLibrary/other.mp4&amp;autostart=false&amp;image=?previewFileLocation?&amp;backcolor=000000&amp;frontcolor=EEEEEE&amp;lightcolor=FFFFFF&amp;screencolor=000000&amp;autostart=false&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;provider=video&amp;duration?" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always">
</object>
```

Can you please tell, where can I set preview image(I have a image url)in the above object tag?

Comment: this might help http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1407439-adding-preview-thumbnails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="fitvid473410"><param name="movie" value="http://demo.assetbank.co.uk/assetbank-standard/tools/jwplayer/player.swf">
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=http://win-hk4iec2ge2r:1111/sites/KL007/Lists/KLDocumentLibrary/other.mp4&amp;autostart=false&amp;image=<image path>?previewFileLocation?&amp;backcolor=000000&amp;frontcolor=EEEEEE&amp;lightcolor=FFFFFF&amp;screencolor=000000&amp;autostart=false&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;provider=video&amp;duration?">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="scale" value="default">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <embed id="player1" width="300px" height="500px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://demo.assetbank.co.uk/assetbank-standard/tools/jwplayer/player.swf" flashvars="file=http://win-hk4iec2ge2r:1111/sites/KL007/Lists/KLDocumentLibrary/other.mp4&amp;autostart=false&amp;image=?previewFileLocation?&amp;backcolor=000000&amp;frontcolor=EEEEEE&amp;lightcolor=FFFFFF&amp;screencolor=000000&amp;autostart=false&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;provider=video&amp;duration?" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always">
    </object>
```